# How do I change the number of columns in Yakuake's first tab?

Tags: terminal, zsh, konsole

I have a welcome message in zsh. When I open a new tab in `yakuake` it displays nicely. However, if I start `yakuake` and press `F12` to show the window, the message is distored due to `yakuake` breaking lines after 68 columns. In `konsole` the message works without issues as `konsole` just remembers my previously set size of the window.

Question: Is there a way I can change this 68 columns to something higher like 80?

**First Tab**

[image]

**All Other Tabs**
[image]